# Hide Image Container if No Image Attachments

Tags: attachments, conditional-tags, images

I have a CPT that displays any attached images via a slider.

However, when there are no attached images the slider still appears.

Is there a way to add a conditional `IF` statement that will hide the slider or at the very least return some inline css that will "display: none" on the container, to the code below? This is part of a `cpt-single.php` page.

```
<ul id="slider" class="exhibit-slide">
  <?php $args = array( 
      'post_type'      => 'attachment', 
      'orderby'        => 'menu_order', 
      'order'          => 'ASC', 
      'post_mime_type' => 'image',
      'post_status'    => null, 
      'numberposts'    => null, 
      'post_parent'    => $post->ID
    );

    $attachments = get_posts( $args );

    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $alt          = get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
            $image_title  = $attachment->post_title;
            $caption      = $attachment->post_excerpt;
            $description  = $attachment->post_content;
  ?>    

    <li>
        <div class="exhibit">
            <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID); ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>">
        </div>
    </li>

  <?php } } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the query before the actualy displaying of the div, then you can run your conditional.  According to [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) it returns an array, so I'm assuming it returns an empty array if posts aren't found, thus we can check is it's not [`! empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
<?php $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 
        'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
        'order' => 'ASC', 
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'post_status' => null, 
        'numberposts' => null, 
        'post_parent' => $post->ID 
    );

    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if( ! empty( $attachments ) ) :
?>
    <ul id="slider" class="exhibit-slide">

        <?php foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $alt = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
            $image_title = $attachment->post_title;
            $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
            $description = $attachment->post_content;
        ?>  

            <li>
                <div class="exhibit">
                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID); ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>">
                </div>
            </li>

        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```